# How to remove a particular character from an entire row of a particular string using perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl

From this string pattern:

```
  "test A dkdkd荴kdklsl skldsls荴lksdkdk skdkd荴kdkls";
```

I am trying to remove this character 荴 from the entire row..

I tried this solution but it only remove the 荴 at the end of the row and not if it contains more than occurrence of it on the same row:

```
   $removeU8374 =~ s/^(test A .*)\N{U+8374}/$1/;
```

I even tried this but still removed only one occurrence of it and not remove all occurrence of 荴 character from the entire row:

```
   $removeU8374 =~ s/^(test A .*)\N{U+8374}/$1/g;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove it everywhere, ignore the rest of the string in your substitution, eg.

```
$removeU8374 =~ s/\N{U+8374}//g;
```

Otherwise, you can loop on your substitution until it no longer matches.

Comment: okay thanks if this is the only solution. I'll just have a to add an if statement to identify the line I want and then remove it.